# django-channels: No route found for path

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I have a Django + Vue.js chat application that I'm trying to connect to django-channels.

To access any chat room, you simply go to:

> http://localhost:8080/rooms/"id"/

My javascript connection looks like this:

```
connectToWebSocket () {
  const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
    `ws://localhost:8000/ws/rooms/${this.$route.params.id}/`
  )

  chatSocket.onopen = this.onOpen
  chatSocket.onclose = this.onClose
  chatSocket.onmessage = this.onMessage
  chatSocket.onerror = this.onError
},
```

My consumers.py:

```
class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
def connect(self):
    self.room_uri = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['uri']
    self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_uri

    # Join room group
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

    self.accept()

def disconnect(self, close_code):
    # Leave room group
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

# Receive message from WebSocket
def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json['message']
    user = text_data_json['user.username']

    # Send message to room group
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            'type': 'chat_message',
            'user': user,
            'message': message
        }
    )

# Receive message from room group
def chat_message(self, event):
    user = event['user']
    message = event['message']

    # Send message to WebSocket
    self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'user': user,
        'message': message
    }))
```

and my routing.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from core import consumers


websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ws/rooms/<uri>/', consumers.ChatConsumer),
]
```

my project routing.py:

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

import core.routing


application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            core.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
})
```

The problem is, I can't connect to the websocket, my django server says:

> [Failure instance: Traceback: : No route found for path 'ws/rooms/759b9a8262ea4b7/'.

What's wrong in my code that I can't connect to a specific room through the websocket?

Full stack trace:

> [Failure instance: Traceback: : No route found for path 'ws/rooms/759b9a8262ea4b7/'.
>   /home/dave/PycharmProjects/chatapp2/back/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/autobahn/websocket/protocol.py:2801:processHandshake
>   /home/dave/PycharmProjects/chatapp2/back/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/txaio/tx.py:429:as_future
>   /home/dave/PycharmProjects/chatapp2/back/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:151:maybeDeferred
>   /home/dave/PycharmProjects/chatapp2/back/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/daphne/ws_protocol.py:82:onConnect
>   ---  ---
>   /home/dave/PycharmProjects/chatapp2/back/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:151:maybeDeferred
>   /home/dave/PycharmProjects/chatapp2/back/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/daphne/server.py:198:create_application
>   /home/dave/PycharmProjects/chatapp2/back/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py:41:**call**
>   /home/dave/PycharmProjects/chatapp2/back/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/routing.py:58:**call**
>   /home/dave/PycharmProjects/chatapp2/back/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/sessions.py:43:**call**
>   /home/dave/PycharmProjects/chatapp2/back/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/sessions.py:141:**call**
>   /home/dave/PycharmProjects/chatapp2/back/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/sessions.py:165:**init**
>   /home/dave/PycharmProjects/chatapp2/back/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/middleware.py:31:**call**
>   /home/dave/PycharmProjects/chatapp2/back/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/routing.py:154:**call**

Comment: You are using Django `urls` aka `re_path` I suggest you to give proper regex to your urlpattern. May be this? `url(r'^ws/rooms/(?P<id>\d+)/', consumers.ChatConsumer)`,

Comment: @RajaSimon thank you, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Can you post your project routing.py?

Comment: @RajaSimon I've added it to my question

Comment: This should work with your setup. r'^ws/rooms/(?P<room_name>[^/]+)/$' I can't think of any other reason why this not works.

Answer (score 14):

You need to use `url`, I had the same problem:

#### Not working

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
  path('ws/chat/<str:room_name>/$', consumers.ChatConsumer),
]
```

#### Working

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^ws/chat/(?P<room_name>[^/]+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer),
]
```

Comment: Fixes the Channels 2.0 tutorial issue

Comment: path must be used without trailing $  (url use regexps, path use it's own simplified syntax)

Comment: Can you add an import for the `url` as well?

Answer (score 8):

Try something like this:

**routing.py (Inside your django app folder)**

```
from django.urls import path
from core import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/rooms/<uri>/', consumers.ChatConsumer),
]
```

**routing.py (Same level as your settings.py)**

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import myapp.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            myapp.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

**And lastly in your settings.py**

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [REDIS_URL],
        },
    },
}

INSTALLED_APPS.append('channels')
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.routing.application'
```

Comment: Can you please send the full stack trace?

Comment: I've added this to the original post

Comment: I've edited my answer after testing the URL - It definately does resolve, the problem may be that you are missing either some code in your settings or you are missing the first routing file which is meant to live on the same level as the `settings.py`

Comment: I've done this all before, it's exactly as in your answer. May my problem depend on consumers.py?

Comment: You may want to specify the type of the url kwarg like this 

 `path('ws/rooms/<uri:str>/', consumers.ChatConsumer)`

Comment: @desiiner. You can try to see if the consumers is an issue by removing all code in the connect function and just leave the self.accept line. Sometimes its not very verbose with where the issue lies

Answer (score 6):

I met the same problem as you,and just now I happened to solve it!
in my ws_client.py I wrote this

```
ws.create_connection("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/alarm")
```

and in routing.py I changed to this below and it worked

```
from django.urls import path
channel_routing = [
    path('alarm',consumers.ws_message),
    # before I wrote 'alarm/', I just change from alarm/ to alarm
]
```

and it worked! you can try it

Answer (score 2):

To anyone new that may be facing this issue. Don't use the `path` pattern matcher with a regular expression. If you wish to do use, use either `url` or `re_path` instead.

**using `path`**

Match pattern without trailing or leading slash (/) and make sure pattern corresponds with client web socket URL

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path("ws/chat/<int:uri>", ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

**Using `re_path` or `url`**

Match pattern without trailing slash (/).

```
url(r'^ws/chat/(?P<uri>[^/]+)/$', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
```

NOTE: I advise using `path` because it's easier to match patterns and read.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the slash from the app.routing routes file solved the problem, I guess it was being counted a duplicate slash in the URL of that socket.

For instance, I had:

```
url(r'/ws/documents/get-df', consumers.DFConsumer.as_asgi())
```

This was not working, but it worked when I removed the first slash before was

```
url(r'ws/documents/get-df', consumers.DFConsumer.as_asgi())
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent like more than an hour to this problem and I found out that django project my default doesn't take asgi.py configuration settings in consideration.

1. Install daphne into your project 
   `python -m pip install daphne`
2. list into your `INSTALLED_APPS` array

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "daphne",
    ...,
]
```

3. Mentioned asgi application object

`ASGI_APPLICATION = "myproject.asgi.application"`

Run your project and see if it connects with your websocket.

For context, my asgi.py file is like this

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from django.urls import path
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

from chat_app.routing import ChatConsumer


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'teacher_gpt_chat.settings')

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/chat', ChatConsumer.as_asgi())
]

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        "websocket": URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns),
    }
)
```

Comment: Django==4.1.5. I replaced "channels" with "daphne". Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

i had similar issue and added .as_asgi() and it worked

`url(r"messages/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/", ChatConsumer.as_asgi())`,

Answer (score 0):

you may need to restart the services, seems it would not automatic reload.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).